# Is there a visualizer for symbols in object files?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang

I have a large .o file with many symbols. The output from `nm` is over 1M lines.

I'd like to see a visual representation, something like a tree or treemap to more easily tell what all those symbols are, with the goal of reducing the size. Is this possible?